Finding the way through the Mists of Forgetfullness
Problem Statement
Welcome to The Dreaming, the place where Fae show their true Miens and get more powerful the deeper they go... wait, I just welcomed you, so you must have entered the Dreaming, right? That means we need to check the Mists of Forgetfulness rules.1
So, You're Glamour 1, because you are an enchanted mortal, but Banality 5, because you are only an enchanted mortal. So your net Glamour is... Banality 4. So, the spreadsheet says, you are:




Rate
Mist Effect
Duration




1 Glamour
Awestruck
Permanent


4 Banality
Angry*
Permanent




Buuut, the descriptors in the right column also says this:

1 Glamour: The Dreaming is a place of new wonders to explore, and sights and sounds often distract the character. Most enchanted mortals are this stage when they enter the Dreaming.
4 Banality: Confusion turns into hatred. Most individuals
with this level of Banality in their souls turn their experience
into hatred to hunt down what they perceive as the world’s
hidden demons.

Wait, the list of effects says that an enchanted mortal is 1 Glamour Awestruck, but the formula says they are 4 Banality Hatred? And we are not even deep enough for the Banalty Cleansing effect beyond the Vale of Mist to have an effect and purge the temporary Banality points.2 Am I missing something here? Are the rules just... ripped apart once more and strewn all over the book and I can't find them?
Question Clarification
You see, from the example above, that this is just one surface effect of the whole mess of trying to figure out what these Mists of Forgetfulness actually are intended to do, or how to handle them with the C20 rules. They are just... feeling abridged and incomplete.
That is compounded by a few strange things I noticed about these strange Mists:

These Mists of Forgetfulness are nowhere mentioned in the core of Changeling 2nd Edition at all!

Or the Storyteller Guide or Player's Handbook for 2nd Edition for the matter.
Denizens of the Dreaming mentions The Mists, but does not detail on what they do.3
Dreams and Nightmares does mention them in the introduction.4, and the spreadsheet seems to come straight from the Appendix.5 But it does not detail on how to handle them any more.



So they were rather obscure to begin with, and the whole Mists of Forgetfulness page is clearly a direct copy-paste, unaltered...
So, is there any more clear write-up of the rules I am missing, or some interaction I am missing out on? Maybe some errata or official commentary that assists in handling them? These Mists seem so... confusing!

1 - Changeling The Dreaming, 20th Anniversary Edition, p.303.
2 - Changeling The Dreaming, 20th Anniversary Edition, p.269.
3 - Denizens of the Dreaming, for 2nd Edition, p.28.
4 - Dreams and Nightmares, for 2nd Edition, p.12.
5 - Dreams and Nightmares, for 2nd Edition, p.125.
